# How to notify a parent class and reflect a change in a data bound observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am having some difficulty reflecting changes in a data bound observable collection.

I have a listbox that is populated with values from the observation collection. When I add or remove items, this is reflected in the bound control. However, when I change the value to be displayed this is not reflected.

For example, Add a week object with a title of 'Week 1' (Works fine) - Now, change the title to 'Hobbies' (Not reflected in control bound to the observable list)

Below is my course management namespace with the parent class **courses** and the child class **weeks**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Windows;

namespace Management.Courses
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Course")]
    class cCourse
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(propertyName);

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public cCourse()
        {
            Weeks = new ObservableCollection<cWeek>();
        }

        #region "Core Properties"
        [DataMember(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Weeks")]
        private ObservableCollection<cWeek> _Weeks;
        public ObservableCollection<cWeek> Weeks
        {
            get
            {
                return _Weeks;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this._Weeks)
                {
                    _Weeks = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Week")]
    class cWeek
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #region "Core Properties"
        [DataMember(Name = "Title")]
        private string _Title { get; set; }
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _Title;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.Title)
                {
                    _Title = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }

            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And in my window, I have as follows:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Core;

namespace Management.Courses
{
    public partial class MgnCourses_Add : Window
    {
        private cCourse oCourse;

        public MgnCourses_Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            oCourse = new cCourse();

            //Set Data Context
            DataContext = oCourse;


            cWeek oWeek = new cWeek();

            //Get/Set week title
            oWeek.Title = "Week " + e.NewValue;

           //Update week listing
           oCourse.Weeks.Add(oWeek);
        }

private void ctrlTopics_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            oCourse.Weeks[ctrlTopics.SelectedIndex].Title = "New String";
        }
    }
}
```

The control binding for the listbox is:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ctrlTopics" Margin="100,131,439,49" ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" MouseDoubleClick="ctrlTopics_MouseDoubleClick">
```

I can see through debugging that the observable list values are changing correctly - It's just not reflected in the listbox.

Any help / pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@M.B has already provided the best solution for your situation. However, I would like to make things a little more clear and add a walk around to the question. The reason that your UI does not reflects the change you made to data is that your code only notify UI about the entire object change

```
Week = other_week;
```

but not the object 's properties change

```
Week.Title = new_week_title;
```

Now, the walk around I mentioned before: just notify UI about the property change explicitly:

```
Week.Title = new_week_title;
PropertyChange(this, nameof(Week));
```

You can also assign new value to current object to invoke the notify event:

```
Week = new Week(new_week_title);
```

However, this action will affect the observable collection since you have assign an object that does not belongs to the existing collection and it can introduce a lot of problems. With that being said, the best solution you should take is @M.B 's solution.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I understand fully. I have implemented M.B's solution but this does not reflect the property change. I have tried to use the 'PropertyChange(this, nameof(Week));' but I'm not sure where it should go.

Comment: What I meant is that right after you change the title of current week, just call PropertyChange() to notify Ui that Current week has changed so Ui could update the new value for CurrentWeek. Title. Something like this:
CurrentWeek.Title = "new title";
PropertyChange (this, nameof(CurrentWeek));

Answer (score 2):

When wanting to use binding with INotifyPropertyChanged and seeing it reflect changes to the UI, you'll need to use the Item `Listbox.Itemtemplate`. This is because the `DisplayMemberPath` is used as a pointer on which `property` from within the object should be used for display. Once it is set it does not keep track of changes that are made from within the object.

So to give an example of how this should work.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ctrlTopics" Margin="100,131,439,49" ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}" 
         MouseDoubleClick="ctrlTopics_MouseDoubleClick">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

To explain the above code, the `Listbox.ItemTemplate` cannot be used in combination with the `DisplayMemberPath`. So instead of using the `DisplayMemberPath` we create a binding within the template.

< Part 2 >

The UI did not receive any notifications because the PropertyChanged event does not get invoked.
The INotifyPropertyChanged Interface should also be implemented on the cWeek class.
Thus giving it the following definition.

`class cWeek : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Lastly, the following

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

could be reduced to and the event should be invoked to let the UI be notified.

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));   
        }
```

Comment: I made the change above to my xaml, however I still see the same my initial problem. If I add a new week or delete a week it reflects the change but not the property name change.

Comment: What are the values that get displayed?

Comment: 'Week 1' not 'New String' . Essentially, the double click title change isn't being reflected in the UI

Comment: Where in the code can the title be changed? Also have you tried setting a debug point in the setter of the Title?
Could you also change the NotifyPropertyChanged(); to NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));. 
I'm currently unable to pinpoint the problem of why it does not get updated..

Comment: I think I've possibly found the issue. When I set the title value it calls 'NotifyPropertyChanged();' however, PropertyChanged is equal to null so it does not call PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); - I'm not sure why

Comment: Ah, you should implement the NotifyPropertyChanged interface in the cWeek class. And the Invoke should be called on the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216532/discussion-between-paul-haydock-and-m-b).